# php string to int not working

Tags: php, int

I am trying to cut an image for small pieces from database. My code here:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$width = $row['width'];
$height = $row['height'];
$new_width = 480;
$new_height = 360;          
$offset_x =  (int)(round($height*360/$width));//100
$offset_y = 0;
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($new_image,$newimg);
```

But in the line `$offset_x`, the `(int)(round($height*360/$width))` is not working. If I put an `intval`, like `100`, all the `images` will cut well, but the offset position is not willing. So how to `true string to int`?

BTW: In this case, I will call and cut image from database in a `foreach`, should I `unset` something after this code in the foreach?

Comment: where is $row set?  What are the values of $height and $width?

Comment: maybe try intval
$offset_x = intval(round($height*360/$width));

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: @ben, `$height`, `$width` from `mysql query => $row['width'] and $row['height']`.

Comment: @fishman: Did you try casting $width and $height as ints? If they are ints then the result should also be an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rarely need to convert strings to numbers in PHP, it does that implicitely pretty well. For example, your code works just fine without any added conversions:

```
<?php
    $height = '100';
    $width = '200';
    $offset = round($height * 360 / $width);
    echo $offset;
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/LJEXIF

The problem you might be having, if it's not giving you the right result, is the priority of operations. Your code,

```
round($height * 360 / $width)
```

Is the equivalent of

```
round($height * (360 / $width))
```

It will first divide `360` by `$width`, then multiply the result by `$height`. If that's what you wanted, then your problem lies elsewhere. You should try and reproduce your problem with test variables on http://codepad.viper-7.com and post it back here.

Comment: Initially i thought that division happens before multiplication but that's not the case according to the operator precedence chart http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php or am i not reading it right ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder it follows standard mathematics priority of operation, PEDMAS (Parenthesis Exponent Division Multiplication Addition Substraction), as you can see here http://codepad.viper-7.com/xOcjTQ. That chart is a ltitle misleading. The elements on top have precedence over the elements towards the bottom. The positioning of the elements within the "operator" column seems to be random.

Comment: Ahh yes Xeon, i'm glad it follows PEDMAS, initially this is what i suspected but after looking at the chart i got super confused. The page says that within the operator column for that row the operators have precedence from left to right which i guess is wrong! Thanks for the clarification.